# how to scan a digit and get value of it by using windows phone application

Tags: windows-phone-7

i am new bee in windows phone application. i am currently using windows phone 7.1 OS in my emulator and device.i have a sticker which contains a digit. i want to scan this code by using camera and save digit into my database. i have not a single clue about scanning value from camera.

i got the code of scan barcodes and qr codes by using cameras.
my tried code is as follows:-

```
 void cam_Initialized(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Succeeded)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
            {
                // Write message.
                txtDebug.Text = "Camera initialized.";

                // Set flash button text.

            });
        }
    }

    void CaptureImage(object sender, PhotoResult e)
    {
        if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ChosenPhoto.Length.ToString());

            //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named myImage.
            //System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage bmp = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            //bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
            //myImage.Source = bmp;
        }
    }


    private void ShutterButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WP7.ScanBarCode.BarCodeManager.StartScan(
            // on success
    (b) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        txtDebug.Text = b;
        NavigationService.GoBack();
    }),
            // on error
    (ex) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        txtDebug.Text = ex.Message;
        NavigationService.GoBack();
    })
            // Default : please, decode any bar-code
    );
        //if (cam != null)
        //{
        //    try
        //    {
        //        // Start image capture.
        //        cam.CaptureImage();
        //        txtDebug.Text = "Image Taken";
        //    }
        //    catch (Exception ex)
        //    {
        //        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        //        {
        //            // Cannot capture an image until the previous capture has completed.
        //            txtDebug.Text = ex.Message;
        //        });
        //    }
        //}
    }
    private int photoCounter = 0;
    void cam_CaptureImageAvailable(object sender, Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs e)
    {
        photoCounter++;
        string fileName = photoCounter + ".jpg";
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            txtDebug.Text = "Captured image available, saving picture.";
        });

        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate()
        {
            txtDebug.Text = "Picture has been saved to camera roll.";
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Aforge.NET Library for Image comparison or Image Filteration.

[Aforge](http://www.aforgenet.com/)

Comment: aforge.net is a image filtration library but i want to scan a digit.